# Importing CSV file does not show points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, point, csv, import

I am currently trying to import a CSV file as a point layer (x and y coordinates are given by the csv file). But when imported, I do not see any points on the map (although the imported layer is active). I tried to reproject the point layer to the correct CRS in order to see it in reference to another linelayer. But then qgis starts to bug and I cannot move the map any more. It keeps jumping to the old position.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

I have already successfully imported other csv files prior to that one, so I really can not explain this behaviour.

This is how I import the csv-file with the x and y coordinates:

[image]

Comment: were you asked to set the CRS after import? If not, it is most likely set to EPSG:4326 by default (you can change default behaviour in the settings -> options -> *CRS* (*KBS* in german) tab). and this would be one of the rare situations where one needs to actually *set* the CRS instead of reprojecting it (which, in fact, does make things worse here...)

Comment: after import can you open the table go to one (the first) feature, right mouse click and then "zoom to object"...what will happen?

Comment: Are all x and y in the range of the crs? Looks like some MGI projection. When one or more of the coordinates having one digit more by mistake it might lead to the problem that it is not viewable.